# How to get the rows of a RecordSet in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

How Can I get the other rows of the RecordSet in VBA/ADO?

I'm using the below code, but that only gives me the first row. What about for example the second item on the third row of the recordset?

```
Debug.Print recordSet.Fields(0)
```

Comment: `Fields(0).Item(1)` property?

Comment: @mehow But the above code `Fields(0).Item(1)` gives me errors.

Comment: @Vahid, did you get time to check the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to loop through the Recordset Object to get all the rows.

```
Public Sub testRecordset()
    Dim rstObj As DAO.Recordset

    Set rstObj = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM tableName")

    Do While Not rstObj.EOF
        Debug.Print rstObj.Fields(0) & " | " & rstObj.Fields(1) & " | " & rstObj.Fields(2)
        rstObj.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rstObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the reference on how to use a Recordset Object : http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was afraid that I won't have direct access like the way we reach a specific element in an array using indices. Do you know why we have this limitation?

Comment: I do not follow. Could you give it another try?

Comment: Let's say we have an array. I reach the element on the 3rd row and 2nd column with something similar to this: `MyArray(2,1)` - assuming that the array is zero-based. Now why can't we just reach a specific element in recordset the same way? For example: `MyRecordSet(2,1)` or something similar that takes the row and column and gives us the value in that position.

Comment: You can always use the GetRows method to fill a variant array, and do exactly what you intend to do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427%28v=office.15%29.aspx